# Why take the last non zero remainder in Euclid's algorithm as GCD?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

So, I do understand why Euclid's algorithm works, it is pretty simple. $$\text{gcd}(a,b) \overset{!}{=} \text{gcd}(b,r) \iff a = cb + r$$

This is because:

$$a = cb + r \land\text{gcd}(a, b) = d \implies d|a \land d|b \implies d|(a-cb) \implies d|r$$ because $r = a -cb$

$$a = cb + r \land\text{gcd}(b, r) = d \implies d|b \land d|r \implies d|(cb+r) \implies d|a$$ because $a = cb+r$

But from this proof I do not see why the last non-zero remainder that comes from a repeated application of the above is actually the GCD. Am I overlooking something or does this proof not in fact tell so?

For example in this sequence, where does it tell in the proof to stop at $\text{gcd}(28,8)$?

$$\begin{align*}
  & \gcd(28, 64) = d\\
  & 64 = 28(2) + 8 && \implies \gcd(28, 64) = \gcd(28, 8)\\
  & 28 = 8(3) + 4 && \implies \gcd(28, 8) = \gcd(8, 4)\\
  & 8 = 4(2) + 0  && \implies d = 4\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: It's because $\gcd(n,0) $ is obviously $n$.

Comment: @MJD but you stop before that even at least sometimes. I made an example in my question post.

Comment: We have $\ (28,64) = (28,8) = (4,8) = (4,0) = 4,\ $ using standard notation $\ (a,b) := \gcd(a,b).\ $ What is not clear about that?

Comment: ah ok, now I see it. thanks.